# How to change the speed of the object in the javascricpt game?

Tags: html, javascript, javascript-framework

I 'm working on an html5 game which works on javascript library called propulsionjs.In which there will 3 different objects with variable speeds, the score is added at the end of the [game](http://www.propulsionjs.com/demos/balloons/game.html)(time limit of 30 seconds).I'm trying to change the speed of the moving object(balloon here) after  15 seconds.The working js file for the game is given here http://pastie.org/2043894 Can anyone help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
setTimeout(function() {
    obj.balloon.red.vspeed = 40;
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Well i tried the code but i the setTimeout function is not working, i.e speed remains the same i tried something like this http://pastie.org/2044014

Comment: @John Kalberer: Thanks for the reply.Well i tried the code but, the setTimeout function is not working, i.e speed remains the same i tried something like this pastie.org/2044014

Comment: @John Kalberer  I'm not able to find the game initiation  function i feel it is function(t) but its not working..

Comment: so I am assuming that the red balloon is now traveling really slow since you set it to 1?

Comment: what is the point of redVSpeed? That's not going to work. You should just change the value directly: `window.setTimeout(function(){red.vspeed = 1;}, 5000);`

Comment: @david That also didn't work for me either(http://pastie.org/2044203), i feel, i need to add game iniation function which i'm not able to figure it out...

Comment: Hmm, that will teach me to skim read. What you actually would need to do is save a reference to the object created in the beget function, and change the vspeed on that.

Comment: put the setTimeout after line 3 and do 
setTimeout(function() { obj.balloon.red.vspeed = 40; }, 15000);